# ALT text not showing up on major email clients like Outlook, Yahoo etc etc

Tags: html, html-email

Most of the major email clients not showing up the ALT text used when images failed to load. I've followed all the emailer standards, and also tried to style the alt tag. No success! Is there a workaround for this? or does it mainly depends on the email engine?

Below is the sample  tag which I use while developing HTML mailers,

```
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="72" height="15" 
     style="display: block; border: 0; outline: 0;"/>
```

Comment: Usually, I do prefer [putting images right inside the email](https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/) as `cid` resources/attachments, and not linking them externally.

Comment: @UweKeim, this is while developing HTML mailers for advertising and broadcasting, we hand code the mailers and do not use any platforms. While testing on "litmus" and "email on acid" i found out that some email clients do not display alt text at all! and i use inline CSS for styling all my content

Comment: Can you please post or update your code to include an example you have actually tried to implement. That will make it easier to spot any issues and debug.

Answer (score 1):

Alt text shows on Outlook desktop, but after a long security notification, and it currently shows on Gmail.

To get it working on Apple clients, make the alt text smaller---via [Remi Parmentier](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/6624-alt-text-not-visible#):

> this is something typical of WebKit, the rendering engine behind all
>   web views on iOS. If your alt text is too long to fit in a single line
>   within the width of your image, it will be made completely invisible.
>   Also, you need to make sure that your alternative text doesn't "touch"
>   the icon displayed by WebKit. You can see the same behavior on Safari
>   or on Apple Mail.
>
> I'd suggest to make your alternative text shorter. Or you can also try
>   to style it and reduce its `font-size` on the `<img>` tag.

For your example, this works:

```
<img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" width="72" height="15" 
style="display: block; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size:10px;"/>
```

Comment: Actually Outlook does show the alt tags but it's after the security notification with the same font/styling